# Setting Default Value of TextBlock when binding to Boolean Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am binding a textblock to a boolean property.  What I am trying to do - if it is `false` I want the value to be `In Progress`  If it is `true` I want it to be `Completed`

I am using C# with a WPF application and the textblocks are part of a treeview.

```
<DataTemplate>
 <Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
     <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Path=BaseNumber, StringFormat='Device Number {0}.'}" Padding="2" Width="200" />
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Path=BaseMode}" Padding="2" />
 </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The TextBlock that is bound to `BaseMode` is the one I want to set the values for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Padding="2" >
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="In Progress"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BaseMode}" Value="true">
                           <Setter Property="Text" Value="Completed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
  </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't bind the `Text` but set up [`DataTriggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) in the `Style`, which then in turn set the `Text` you want for true/false. (Also watch out for [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to not override the style)

Answer (score 2):

What you can use is a ValueConverter. See if the following tutorials help you:

http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

http://drwpf.com/blog/category/value-converters/